# unable the zip folder with adm-zip NodeJs

Tags: node.js, adm-zip

I use the adm-zip(Module NodeJs ) to zip Floder, with Method addLocalFolder().The operation end successfully, but when i try to unzip folder i get the Error 2 ' file or directory not exist!'as additional info i have the right size of zip when zip operation is end.
Thank you every one.

Answer (score 0):

The archive files produced by adm-zip do not seem to work on certain systems.  Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15532326/1134405