# Compressing multiple files using zlib

Tags: node.js, compression, gzip, zlib

The below code will compress one file. How can I compress multiple files

```
var gzip = zlib.createGzip();
var fs = require('fs');
var inp = fs.createReadStream('input.txt');
var out = fs.createWriteStream('input.txt.gz');

inp.pipe(gzip).pipe(out);
```

Comment: if you want to compress entire directories structures, try to get the names of the directories and files use recursive function. you can use other modules, but this is the theory.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Something that you could use:

```
var listOfFiles = ['firstFile.txt', 'secondFile.txt', 'thirdFile.txt'];

function compressFile(filename, callback) {
    var compress = zlib.createGzip(),
        input = fs.createReadStream(filename),
        output = fs.createWriteStream(filename + '.gz');

    input.pipe(compress).pipe(output);

    if (callback) {
        output.on('end', callback);
    }
}
```

#1 Method:

```
// Dummy, just compress the files, no control at all;
listOfFiles.forEach(compressFile);
```

#2 Method:

```
// Compress the files in waterfall and run a function in the end if it exists
function getNext(callback) {
    if (listOfFiles.length) {
        compressFile(listOfFiles.shift(), function () {
            getNext(callback);
        });
    } else if (callback) {
        callback();
    }
}

getNext(function () {
    console.log('File compression ended');
});
```

Comment: I want a single zip file containing all the files together.

Comment: The zip file has a more specific file format than just concatenating the files http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_%28file_format%29, let me npm this for you? https://www.npmjs.org/package/zip-paths

Comment: I'm a little confused why this answer has been accepted, since it doesn't seem to answer the question (as per user3180402's comment above ^)

Comment: He just added a loop and nothing was concatenated.

Answer (score 10):

Gzip is an algorithm that compresses a string of data. It knows nothing about files or folders and so can't do what you want by itself. What you can do is use an archiver tool to build a single archive file, and then use gzip to compress the data that makes up the archive:

- https://github.com/mafintosh/tar-stream

Also see this answer for more information: [Node.js - Zip/Unzip a folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15530435/node-js-zip-unzip-a-folder)

Answer (score 8):

The best package for this (and the only one still maintained and properly documented) seems to be [`archiver`](https://github.com/archiverjs/node-archiver)

```
var fs = require('fs');
var archiver = require('archiver');
var output = fs.createWriteStream('./example.tar.gz');
var archive = archiver('tar', {
    gzip: true,
    zlib: { level: 9 } // Sets the compression level.
});

archive.on('error', function(err) {
  throw err;
});

// pipe archive data to the output file
archive.pipe(output);

// append files
archive.file('/path/to/file0.txt', {name: 'file0-or-change-this-whatever.txt'});
archive.file('/path/to/README.md', {name: 'foobar.md'});

// Wait for streams to complete
archive.finalize();
```

Comment: This does the job perfectly with a minimum amount of fuss.

Answer (score 2):

```
module.exports = class ZlibModule{

listOfImages = ['a.png','b.jpg'];
fs = require('fs')
zlib = require('zlib');

constructor(req,res){
    this.req = req;
    this.res = res;
}

compressOperation(){
    this.listOfImages.forEach((value,index) => {
        const readStream = this.fs.createReadStream(rootDirectory+'/modules/zlibModule/images/'+value);
        const writeStream = this.fs.createWriteStream(rootDirectory+'/modules/zlibModule/'+value+'.gz');
        const compress = this.zlib.createGzip()
        readStream
            .on('error',(error)=>{
                this.res.end(`${error.path} path does't exist`)
            })
            .pipe(compress)
            .pipe(writeStream)
            .on('error',(error)=>{
                console.log(error);
                this.res.end(`Something went to wrong`)
            })
            .on('finish',()=>{
                if(index+1 === this.listOfImages.length) this.res.end("Done");
            })
    });
}
}
```