# Why isn't chrome downloading the files included in the response?

Tags: java, spring-boot, servlets, httpresponse, bytearrayoutputstream

I am currently running a Java Spring Boot program that should return a response that includes two Excel files (.xlsx) as ByteArrayOutputStream's in the ServletOutputStream as Content-Disposition: attachment;

However, upon returning that response to chrome, it isn't downloading anything.

The Excel files are generated using the Apache POI and then they're being written to a ByteArrayOutputStream.

Here's my code on the file generation

```
protected ByteArrayOutputStream export() throws IOException{
    XSSFWorkbook workbook = new SXXFWorkbook();
    //some stuff happens
    
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    workbook.write(byteArrayOutputStream);
    workbook.close();
    return byteArrayOutputStream;
}
```

Here is my endpoint that processes the request and returns the response.

```
@GetMapping("/${pageLinks.excelPage}/download")
public void getExcelDownload(HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    // Set the response type and specify the boundary string
    response.setContentType("multipart/x-mixed-replace;boundary=END");

    // Set the content type based on the file type you need to download
    String contentType = "Content-type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";

    ByteArrayOutputStream inventorySheet = inventoryExcel.export();
    ByteArrayOutputStream deductionsSheet = deductionsExcel.export();

    ServletOutputStream responseOutputStream = response.getOutputStream();

    // Print the boundary string
    responseOutputStream.println();
    responseOutputStream.println("--END");

    List<Pair<String, ByteArrayOutputStream>> files = new ArrayList<>();

    files.add(new Pair<>("Deductions.xlsx", deductionsSheet));
    files.add(new Pair<>("Inventory.xlsx", inventorySheet));

    for (Pair<String, ByteArrayOutputStream> file : files) {

        // Print the content type
        responseOutputStream.println(contentType);
        responseOutputStream.println("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=" + file.getKey());
        responseOutputStream.println();

        // Write the contents of the file
        file.getValue().writeTo(responseOutputStream);
        file.getValue().close();

        // Print the boundary string
        responseOutputStream.println();
        responseOutputStream.println("--END");
        responseOutputStream.flush();
    }

    // Print the ending boundary string
    responseOutputStream.println("--END--");
    responseOutputStream.flush();
    responseOutputStream.close();
}
```

The code that I'm using here comes from [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36886141/download-multiple-files-java-spring) which links to [this example post](https://javadigest.wordpress.com/2012/02/13/downloading-multiple-files-using-multipart-response/)
I also looked at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9344455/unable-to-send-a-multipart-mixed-request-to-spring-mvc-based-rest-service) as well to see if there was something wrong with the original links, and I couldn't find anything.

I have tried adding the --END boundary to the top and bottom of each loop, to no success.

**EDIT**

*I assume this has something to do with the file.getValue().writeTo(responseOutputStream); line, but from what I found I thought this would work.*

**EDIT 2**

*Firefox will allow me to download both files, but upon opening the files, there's a notification stating "We found a problem with some content" and asks to recover. Clicking yes seems to show the proper information and states that some content may have been repaired or discarded. This doesn't happen when writing to a file (FileOutputStream)*

Here's the response that chrome shows

```
--END
Content-type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=Deductions.xlsx

PK˜`*S[Content_Types].xmlµSËnÂ0ü•È×*6ôPUCÇ©ô\{“Xø%¯¡ð÷]8”R‰
qòcfgfWöd¶q¶ZCB|ÃÆ|Ä*ð*hã»†},^ê{Va–^K<4lÈfÓÉb+ªõØ°>çø ªœD"xBÚœÌtLˆR-eâv4º*ø>×¹h°éä  Z¹²¹zÜÝé†É­Q2S,±öúH´Þòvà`o"ÞUÏRÙµC(2q†Ãqa9SÝ
&
ÿŠÚÖ(ÐA­•p(ªtS6°Ï9—)¿JG‚‚ÈsBQ4¿Äû0œeXˆ9u‹1ÔØdg9ö2~Ï‰^Óï+~®˜#oí‰)”rÍ ÐÊ4þ”ûWHËÏ–×ó/Ãþ/ûD1,ãC1|ïé7PK‘,(¼;PK˜`*S_rels/.rels­’ÁJ1†_%Ì½›miÚ‹½‰Ô“ÙÝ°›LHFÝ¾½Á‹¶lAÁã03ßÿ1Év?‡I½S.ž£uÓ‚¢hÙùØx9>®î@ÁèpâHNT`¿Û>Ó„RWÊàSQ•‹A$Ýk]ì@KÃ‰bítœJ-s¯Ú{Ò›¶½Õù'Î™êàäƒ[ƒ:bîIÌ“þà<¾2MÅÖÆ)ÑoB¹ë¼¥¶o¢,d_L€^vÙ|»8¶O™ë&¦ôß24EGn•jeñõâWŒnŒ,gú›ÒõGÑ
~Q/„ôÙØ}PKn2KåJPK˜`*SdocProps/app.xmlMŽÁ
Â0Dï‚ÿro·z‘4¥ ‚'{ÐéÖšMHVéç›“zœæñT·úE¼1e¨•»º‘É†ÑÑ³•û¥:ÊNo7jH!bb‡Y”åVÎÌñíŒÞäºÌT–)$o¸Äô„0MÎâ9Ø—GbØ7Ípe¤Ç*~R«>ÆÅYÃEB÷Ñ¤nWÿ½‚ŸƒþPK6nƒ!“¸PK˜`*SdocProps/core.xmlm]KÃ0†ÿJÈ}›¤êBÛ!Ê@PXQ¼É±-6$ÑnÿÞ´Î
ê]’÷9'o¹=è}€½5f9ÅŒ´ª7m›]vQˆÂ(1X>BÀÛº”ŽKëaï­{(yLàÒU¸‹ÑqB‚ì@‹'Â¤ðÕz-bºú–8!ßD¤ ôŒhˆB‰(È$ÌÜbÄ'¥’‹Ò½ûa(I`
&ÂrF~Ø^‡æd!¡_¨qóq5#Fžïnæå³ÞL—€ëò¤æÒƒˆ Pðxt©’ïäiuuÝìp]Ð‚et“1Ú°sN×|½y)É¯ùIøu¶¾¾L…t€ö÷7·<—äOÍõ'PK-ÔË±PK˜`*Sxl/sharedStrings.xml…Ò]kƒ0àûÂþCÈ½M´kYE-²¥P¨Zfº±Ë ™
š¸|ŒíßÏ±A™
ìò<çÍ{ní>†¼s¥;)bè/1\T²îDÃ3Ý{wp—Ü,"­
¨¤&†Ý›å÷˜j„ŽakÌ"¤«–L/åÈÅ´y•j`fUƒô¨8«uË¹z`¼AëL"Ý%‘IJÃ”   AyÎÁ&Ä¤Ù‚ˆúÖáz;A„L¡ïøï+jö9×Lº”Z®üÌká\ÐÖ*—ïUçÐ’«\-Ò°~Ž©m¼`ëÒvªuŽvkàÔ•SogŠþDžÈãa €d§cñBH9/É‹Üû?uJéäôÊiAÓãÑôÓ’/PKÈ2‘—PK˜`*S
xl/styles.xmlíYËŽ›0ÝWê? ï;’L’
U#¥ê¦‹ÎŒÔ­†XõgJæëkc’*'ˆ–ªÙûrï90Ç%x()q^‘(0g!ÜyÀA,æ   fY^žç¦à!zÿ.(äš §%BÒQ¬ÁRÊü£ëñQXÜñ1u&å‚B©¦"s‹\ ˜ºˆ×÷¼{—BÌ@°SY81_1¸Qr¶‹=`"QP¼9¯(mZœÊ‹9áÂÁ,A%JB0Õ1)2Yà…À ¤˜¬MØ×JjG1ãB]Ãb~âløFÀ­¢_3•b…nÿ1À¿¨ùïÜ*þü
«…Â„l·¼10(È¡”H°¹š8õøy£0Îj˜*ïLvÅÏ®í+
NpriºJË÷÷äQµ)»ÂÖcÿ(duPwsÁE¢™Íý€M(
J¥*8[ê£ä¹~6\JNÕ Á0ãM°©¨
6F„<éîç{º‡]¦Žic¾$ºƒqô3Ý• zh`ÌDã7Ñv¶êz.ÇuÊtKp¬zp¾ÚyNÖs®•T6
ÔÂÎEL:?ÌŸQ)k¹LÓùWÐ™À§
åR  øÆ%”U³:SK.ð›‚Ð/Y¬R8+mØ_i£þJ÷WÚ}¥Mú+mÚ3i“´ÙNÚð´4•µ'íëŠ.˜Wß {'qÊ$-<öð=8éW<µ_w®ÄÚÊ;WbíÜ+±6êÎ•XûrçJ¬m¸s%“«ýÃÒ&Þ9ºŒ ókŸõVšïõWÚ5Ýñï¤±ùÖžyÍ†Õ$²¶Ä¶DÖŽ×–ÈÚÐÚYûU["ë&°-‘uK×–¨óÍ­?ŒÕh÷ÇCôPK*ú-Š­PK˜`*Sxl/workbook.xmlŽÁNÃ0DïHüƒµwj§ Qœ^*¤Þ8î®½i¬Æv´ë¶|>NªGN«Ñ¼™fóqAbŸ¢†j¥@`´ÉùxÔð±{xM{×\)Dá#kèsk)Ùö¯Òˆ±8]¢`r‘t”<Ç=bƒ\+õ,ƒñn    5ý'#u·¸Mö0æ[á`rYË½ÚŸeï$œÉX½ª'
A¶Íä|z¼ò/8IalöÜ›ƒ5qò8o^®ˆ& †-º³kAPíÚ¹G3³+²šS–W¹”µßPK™†¾ZÜbPK˜`*Sxl/_rels/workbook.xml.rels­‘MkÃ0@ÿŠÑ}qÒÁ£n/cÐk?~€°•84±¥µË¿¯»ÃÖ@;ô$Œð{´\ƒ:Qæ>MUƒ¢`£ëCgà°ÿxzÅ‚Áá˜ˆa½Zni@)_Ø÷‰Ua6àEÒ›Öl=ÈULÊ¦yD)ÏÜé„öˆéE]¿è|Ë€9Smœ¼q
¨=æŽÄ{Ìäv’KW\VS¢ÿhcÛö–Þ£ý)È»žÁAßYÜÄÈ4Ðã+¾©éŸõç˜ì‰äZ^Fóè’Á5FÏ®½ºPKgë¢¨Õ4PK˜`*Sxl/worksheets/sheet1.xmlu•[o›0Çß'í; ?m‡ @ÕÜ‘V©Z×í™“ FÆIÚ}úù\›e/‰/¿sáìãùÝ[]9gL»’41€#8¸ÉÉ¾l1xþ¹ù6wÉçOó¡¯Ýcæpƒ¦‹Á‘±6rÝ.?â:ëF¤Å
ß)­3Æ§ôàv-ÅÙ^Õ•ë{ÞÄ­³²É|_Ö¸Š‹ÜÃ(…p“¹„•øÒcGÄ~!äULÒ}xŽ,{yÂÎæsFO˜{m³;ïOmU²øâK:–1ƒ‚’?¸áF¤ýŽ¶ÄUÅƒ"àd9+Ïø‘ÛÅà…0Fj±/‘ÎE†í]WçfŽûœ7RƒGêìq‘*öƒ\v¸<yV0ÉïÌIÕÉ_§.…ìÀ©³7ù)÷ìä‰üóSÇ£þVKò+Epe,C­2–%sJ.ÖÜ¥Üs?<XÇP«çÄ›»gaz%&áKÚÄÒ$$|›X™ÄXÈ&Ö&Hbl“˜H"°‰­I„’˜ØÄÎ$¦’m"5‰™$¦šp¹zZB¿—pá›zÒf6PÈB”Ìp óÊb®B”^[Œ’´ÞXŒÔÞZŒ’ôÞYŒO-FI'·õBúÈ!ÓHU†·Æâ_Çv˜T‘àª41„ÚAhiU18»í`j8˜cYèëòLwªºþ?·ÈSÛ¢°Eòôüðe¢ÅôëÜ-¬«tÅÆ–(Z±U5¶BÑjˆ­{,ÐØEë!¶é±‰Æ6(Ú±m…Û¢h;Äv=6ÕØE»!–öØìCèEÜúT…pöUczÀ¢)wNNN
SÇJ¯^ß¥H”j¸Dipk=ŒÒP¶Ë÷â‰8à‡ŒÊ¦sTKç¯É(äg¯ „a*fü$ù»¥'oú’U]\ŽùcrµAôó˜üPKÈýÐ¹½RPK˜`*S‘,(¼;[Content_Types].xmlPK˜`*Sn2KåJ|_rels/.relsPK˜`*S6nƒ!“¸šdocProps/app.xmlPK˜`*S-ÔË±kdocProps/core.xmlPK˜`*SÈ2‘—°xl/sharedStrings.xmlPK˜`*S*ú-Š­
xl/styles.xmlPK˜`*S™†¾ZÜbÈxl/workbook.xmlPK˜`*Sgë¢¨Õ4á  xl/_rels/workbook.xml.relsPK˜`*SÈýÐ¹½Rþ
xl/worksheets/sheet1.xmlPK      ?
--END
Content-type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=Inventory.xlsx

PK˜`*S[Content_Types].xmlµSËnÂ0ü•È×*6ôPUCÇ©ô\{“Xø%¯¡ð÷]8”R‰
qòcfgfWöd¶q¶ZCB|ÃÆ|Ä*ð*hã»†},^ê{Va–^K<4lÈfÓÉb+ªõØ°>çø ªœD"xBÚœÌtLˆR-eâv4º*ø>×¹h°éä  Z¹²¹zÜÝé†É­Q2S,±öúH´Þòvà`o"ÞUÏRÙµC(2q†Ãqa9SÝ
&
ÿŠÚÖ(ÐA­•p(ªtS6°Ï9—)¿JG‚‚ÈsBQ4¿Äû0œeXˆ9u‹1ÔØdg9ö2~Ï‰^Óï+~®˜#oí‰)”rÍ ÐÊ4þ”ûWHËÏ–×ó/Ãþ/ûD1,ãC1|ïé7PK‘,(¼;PK˜`*S_rels/.rels­’ÁJ1†_%Ì½›miÚ‹½‰Ô“ÙÝ°›LHFÝ¾½Á‹¶lAÁã03ßÿ1Év?‡I½S.ž£uÓ‚¢hÙùØx9>®î@ÁèpâHNT`¿Û>Ó„RWàSQ•‹A$Ýk]ì@KÃ‰bítœJ-s¯Ú{Ò›¶½Õù'Î™êàäƒ[ƒ:bîIÌ“þà<¾2MÅÖÆ)ÑoB¹ë¼¥¶o¢,d_L€^vÙ|»8¶O™ë&¦ôß24EGn•jeñõâWŒnŒ,gú›ÒõGÑ
~Q/„ôÙØ}PKn2KåJP˜`*SdocProps/app.xmlMŽÁ
Â0Dï‚ÿro·z‘4¥ ‚'{ÐéÖšMHVéç›“zœæñT·úE¼1e¨•»º‘É†ÑÑ³•û¥:ÊNo7jH!bb‡Y”åVÎÌñíŒÞäºÌT–)$o¸Äô„0MÎâ9Ø—GbØ7Ípe¤Ç*~R«>ÆÅYÃEB÷Ñ¤nWÿ½‚ŸƒþPK6nƒ!“¸PK˜`*SdocProps/core.xmlm]KÃ0†ÿJÈ}›¤êBÛ!Ê@PXQ¼É±-6$ÑnÿÞ´Î
ê]’÷9'o¹=è}€½5f9ÅŒ´ª7m…›]vQˆÂ(1X>BÀÛº”ŽKëaï­{(yLàÒU¸‹ÑqB‚ì@‹'Â¤ðÕz-bºú–8!ßD¤ ôŒhˆB‰(È$ÌÜbÄ'¥’‹Ò½ûa(I`
&ÂrF~Ø^‡æd!¡_¨qóq5si#Fžïnæå³ÞL—€ëò¤æÒƒˆ Pðxt©’ïäiuuÝìp]Ð‚et“1Ú°sN×|½y)É¯ùIøu¶¾¾L…t€ö÷7·<—äOÍõ'PK-ÔË±PK˜`*Sxl/sharedStrings.xmlmÒÁNÃ0àû$Þ!Ê½KÖ±i«ÒLb'‡vÚ9jM©MJâ x{‚@š9úóÛ‡ˆÃÇ4’wp^[SÒÕ’S¦µ6}IÏÍ1ÛÑƒ¼[ï‘´6Œ¡%Áè·WˆcŒ/é€8Œùv€Iù¥ÁÄÎ«u“ÂXºžùÙêü€ÓÈrÎ·lRÚP)¼–eÊaAêó3Ùœ“ê´x4ÝlŠÍ>‚`(ûŽÿ>  ¦SŸ·z²)mø_ 3ÉF3—ò£Ó ­—šbQ·X…>Ë÷)]ó¤®þ­ƒ9ãiÍ“ºNêý²¿·¿4ÕÓ5ÁâO_PK©Cxð7PK˜`*S
xl/styles.xmlí˜ËŽ›0†÷•ú–÷&Í¥FÕH©ºé¢“JÝ:`ˆU_q¦dž¾6&  ©2  Q5›`Îùýaà·‰÷3
ž±Ìˆà>ß À<á‰¬–æð!xÿÎËÔŽâ§
Æ
è
žùp£TúÉq²pƒÊîDŠ¹>ÉÒ]™8Y*1Š2SÄ¨ãŽFS‡!Âaàñ-[2•Pl¹òá:~Œ¸3h#—½€gD5›Óy¡ BÂ#œãˆa›õˆ(YKR"FèÎ†](PË<F¸&èØQìïY€knÃªXÛ®’[|øþEæ›ÀpŠC¦…¥‡…im ðR¤–|©; l¯v)ö!¼”)ò®dGHþú"Ñ®~E&(‰Þš®Ó’ÇÓ•sR,N¥ð Yô¥¯…ŒôÞ`ñc¸Å±Òå’$sT"5)”L7"‚Á5ì+Ê†–
1¥OfCñ3>ÑÎc`w_#³)æì›¨lZÛ1úU5«]‘-6o×y|àµêñõj€Ò”î–ÂOWàé§0ás~K”®p®*^¿>œÛ`8ø¼ò„Òß…BªØÿ-´ÆFHò¢%Ìê,¯¢Ým2\´ÃE›m6\´ùÀÐfG´Åíþ2šÎ:Aû¶ek,—ÅgÝÉ‰ÊE\2É{~.zgƒ»3®í×“Ô¶òÎIj;wç$µºs’Ú¾Ü9ImîœdÖØ?jÚDïü[o\Ñ[´›º:®×dN+ˆnKgì±¥eöØÒKû@li²} ¶tß>[ÚrˆÓÆ.Ù9³S~ëÖñ¯üàPKn)óxÿPK˜`*Sxl/workbook.xmlŽÁNÃ0†ïH¼Cäû–”!UÓ]Row/u×hMR9¡ƒ·'íTàÈÉúåÏ¿¿jÿé1G¼†b«@7¡µþ¤áíð²y„}}{S]Ÿ!œEæ}ÔÐ§4–RFÓ“Ã¸
#ù¼é;L9òIÆ‘ ÛØ%7È;¥¤CëáÚPò:B×YCÏÁ|8òéZÂ4`Ê¶±·c„úÇì•E‹‰Š'u¯¡Ã!Èºš7ï–.ñœ£@“ìD<jP3'ÿ€‹ó:…GG?eƒÀ_ ¸´­nÚˆir,–’õR®¿êoPKîÓH¥ÝaPK˜`*Sxl/_rels/workbook.xml.rels­‘MkÃ0@ÿŠÑ}qÒÁ£n/cÐk?~€°•84±¥µË¿¯»ÃÖ@;ô$Œð{´\ƒ:Qæ>MUƒ¢`£ëCgà°ÿxzÅ‚Áá˜ˆa½Zni@)_Ø÷‰Ua6àEÒ›Öl=ÈULÊ¦yD)ÏÜé„öˆéE]¿è|Ë€9Smœ¼q
¨=æŽÄ{Ìäv’KW\VS¢ÿhcÛö–Þ£ý)È»žÁAßYÜÄÈ4Ðã+¾©éŸõç˜ì‰äZ^Fóè’Á5FÏ®½ºPKgë¢¨Õ4PK˜`*Sxl/worksheets/sheet1.xmlmÔ[o›0àûIû–¯¶‹…ƒIÒ" j„H«T­ëví“ FÆMÚýúù@©mõ&±áùló’|ÉÍkÛ€3aCM»3Ò•ôPwÇ>þÎ\Á›ìë—äBÙóp"„QÐ
)<qÞÇž7”'ÒâaF{Ò‰;e-æbÊŽÞÐ3‚ª¨m¼Ð÷^‹ëfÉ¡nI'wŒT)¼
â}½,QöOM.ƒ1rë'JŸådH¡8"ÇO¤!%'bÎÙ‹ö¸#àí¡ojžÂP>ÈÀ1')¬ýG:QDûŸ¤âkÒ4bO.y}&÷¢.…O”sÚÊûê jqyÀþ“»Þt6sü~æ\EpÏÀTø¥á¿è¥ õñ$NÌÅ±Ä%mõ  ÚZ¦A‹_Õ÷¥>ðS
‘/Ï_¾b×¿ú’zJ¹¹.V[m0ÇYÂè0Y-–”ƒ[±ŽØlè«çÌO¼³,ÅÊ¡-Ö¦@J„¶Ø˜"RÙbkŠ¹‘-rS,”˜ÛbgŠ¥[¦¸Rbi‹½)®•¸š„'Ò›"ß#\…f„¾ª¹v²ˆŽ9prÞXfÚIzkuàd[F‡8iï,£ãœ¼ËèÀ'ñ½etäÁâó¼üAŽãhúùEæúÎ+YEú®|Uöðx÷m…âUø=ñ*3b­BRk¯]µU0©
Š7®ÚŽ*œÔÅ[Wå£B“ÊQœ»j7ªhR;ï\UŒj>©Å…«ö£Z|$ÅEô¡tàžñïñ‘Üav¬»èÆ$zâl9‡ ¢”&g¢»Dó&h]JAÀt/RcÑÇZÙY¦ŸýPKl"¬tiPK˜`*S‘,(¼;[Content_Types].xmlPK˜`*Sn2KåJ|_rels/.relsPK˜`*S6nƒ!“¸šdocProps/app.xmlPK˜`*S-ÔË±kdocProps/core.xmlPK˜`*S©Cxð7°xl/sharedStrings.xmlPK˜`*Sn)óxÿ
âxl/styles.xmlPK˜`*SîÓH¥Ýa•xl/workbook.xmlPK˜`*Sgë¢¨Õ4¯ xl/_rels/workbook.xml.relsPK˜`*Sl"¬tiÌ
xl/worksheets/sheet1.xmlPK      ?{

--END
--END--
```

Chrome just shows a black page with a white square in the middle that it thinks is an image (right clicking it shows save image options)
[image: Chrome display after response]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the reason why this wasn't working on chrome but it was working on firefox.

Chromium removed support for x-mixed-support and multiple file downloads per request, according to [this update](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=249132).

I took the advice of other posts I saw (can't find the links now) to make JavaScript open two new tabs for each download.

Zipping the files is also an option, but is a little less convenient for my use case.

Answer (score 1):

You are returning multiple files directly. To respond multiple file compress them and send them as zip file. Also in the code you are first setting the content type and then updating the contentType.

```
    // Set the response type and specify the boundary string
    response.setContentType("multipart/x-mixed-replace;boundary=END");

    // Set the content type based on the file type you need to download
    String contentType = "Content-type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
```

You can take a look in the following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31434405/nodejs-send-multiple-files-per-response) for returning multiple files in a response.