# Upload folder (containing files & subfolders) into Google Drive using the Drive API in Node.js

Tags: node.js, directory, upload, google-drive-api, node-modules

I have zip file in my Google Drive. And I want to unzip it and store back in Google Drive using Node.JS

I implement code for download file from drive and extract file.

Now I am trying to implement code for  upload this folder in Google Drive.
But I am not able to implement this.
So I want help for **Upload folder into google drive using drive api in node.js**

Or any node module for this ?

Folder contains man sub folders and files like images and pdf etc.

Anyone please help me for this

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your current situation from `But I am not able to implement this.`. Can I ask you about the detail of your current issue and your goal?

Comment: Hi, I am trying to make MERN project in which user will provide link (Google drive link or any index link) of zip file. In backend I will extract this zip file and Extracted folder is upload in my google drive using Node.JS and I will send back google drive ink of that folder to the user. So, in backend code till Extract folder in completed. Now i want to implement code that Extracted folder (contains subfolders and files) upload in google drive. But I don't know how ?

Comment: Thank you for replying. In your goal, you want to unzip a zip file and upload the files to Google Drive. Is my understanding correct? If my understanding is correct, it is required to use Drive API. In your situation, you have already been able to use Drive API?

Comment: Yes, Your understanding is correct. And I am also able to use Drive API.

Comment: Thank you for replying. For example, you can see the sample script for uploading the files to Google Drive using googleapis for Node.js at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-drive-api%5D+upload+%5Bnode.js%5D). And, about the method for unzipping, you can see the sample script at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15530435/7108653). How about combining them? If these were not useful, I apologize.

Comment: Thank You for giving you time. 
I see your refrences but i can't found proper solution. I found only file upload to Google drive that i already know.
I want to upload full foler with same folder tree.
Thank You

Answer (score 0):

**TL:DR; direct answer**

The Google Drive team created a [Node.js sample app](https://github.com/googlearchive/drive-zipextractor) in 2014 that does what you're asking, however as of 2021, it is no longer being maintained, so feel free to fork and improve/modernize it as desired.

**EXTRA info**

If you're completely new to Google APIs, I created some getting started content awhile back (in Python, so if you don't do Python, use it as pseudocode to help get you started):

- To learn how to use Google APIs, create API projects, use the [Developers Console](http://console.developers.google.com), see [this video](http://youtu.be/DYAwYxVs2TI?list=PLOU2XLYxmsILOIxBRPPhgYbuSslr50KVq&index=2) — UI has changed but the concepts are still the same.
- [Walkthrough of authorization boilerplate code](http://youtu.be/h-gBeC9Y9cE?list=PLOU2XLYxmsILOIxBRPPhgYbuSslr50KVq&index=3) — use any [supported language](http://developers.google.com/api-client-library) to access Google APIs.
- Intro to using the Google Drive API v2 (listing your Drive files), see [this video](http://youtu.be/Z5G0luBohCg?list=PLOU2XLYxmsILOIxBRPPhgYbuSslr50KVq&index=4). The code has been updated/improved since the video was published... see the [codelab](https://g.co/codelabs/gsuite-apis-intro) and [repo](https://github.com/googleworkspace/gsuite-apis-intro) for the latest version. There's also more in the code deep dive [post](http://wescpy.blogspot.com/2014/11/authorized-google-api-access-from-python.html).
- To learn about the Google Drive API *v3* (up/downloading files), see [this blogpost & video](http://developers.googleblog.com/2016/01/google-drive-uploading-downloading.html).
- NOTE: Drive API v3 is newer, requires fewer API calls, and has better performance vs. v2 but v2 isn't deprecated yet
- [QuickStart example in Node.js](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/quickstart/nodejs) demonstrating basic API usage to listing files in your Google Drive similar to the Python example above

If you already have experience with Google Workspace (formerly G Suite, Google Apps, Google "Docs") APIs, here are more videos I helped produce:

- [Drive API video library](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/videos)
- Entire [Google Workspace (G Suite) Dev Show video series](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLOU2XLYxmsIJJFx_MVCQJ7eWF3gDxklgJ)